# How to add a new property to the already exsisting model with loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

Am a student currently working on a exsisting project.i need to add some extra properties in an exsisting model without creating a new model with the LoopBack..how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just update your json model with the property you want to add. Or you can also use loopback CLI to add the property `lb property`. Then you need to restart your server and that's it. You can read about updating models in the [docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Customizing-models.html)